# How to eliminate backtracking-leading common prefix in code like {a, b}, a, c?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I am writing a recursive-discent parser for a simplified C language.
The first rules I encountered (in EBNF, heavily simplified) is

```
program = {declaration}, {function_definition}, main_function_definition;
declaration = "int", identifier, ["=", init_value], ";";
function_definition = "int", identifier, "(", [formal_params], ")", block;
main_function_definition = "int", "main", "(", ")", block;
```

How to eliminate backtracking-leading common prefix `"int"` of `program`'s all tree parts?
I failed on using left-factoring to do so.

Comment: @NikolayHandzhiyski Could you provide a sentense for grammar `A={a, c}, a, b` to be ambiguous please? I cannot come up with one.

Comment: `{a b} a c` is **non-ambiguous** (unambiguous if you like the word) as I have written up by copying your title. If you use `,` for a concatenation then it is `{a, c}, a, b`.

Answer (score 1):

The following slightly perverse grammar works (I think) but the resulting parse tree needs to be rotated in order to associate types and names with their corresponding definition. (This is similar to what needs to be done to correct the parse tree from a algebraic expression grammar.) The basic principle at work here is that the regular expression `(a b)* a c` can be rewritten as `a (b a)* c`, which is effectively a form of left-factoring. In this grammar, that transformation is effectively done twice, with a small adjustment to deal with `main`:

```
program = "int", [decls], "main", "(", ")", body;
decls = identifier, {var-decl}, {func-decl};
func-decl = "(", ")", [formal-params], body, "int", [identifier];
var-decl = ["=", expr], ";", "int", [identifier];
```

The main complication to be solved is the unnecessary (IMHO) insistence on a particular order of declarations. If you instead allowed declarations to be freely interspersed, you'd have a much easier task; you could do a simple left-factoring as in the [answer by @500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69676921/1566221), which does not require rejigging the parse tree. This is essentially the strategy used in the grammar in the C standard.

If you insist on the ordering constraint, you could do the check in the associated semantic action instead of relying on the grammar to reject undesired declaration orders. That would also allow you to issue more informative error messages. ("Variables must be declared before functions" instead of "Unexpected '='".)

None of the above is really relevant to writing a recursive descent parser, unless you insist that the recursive descent parser slavishly follow the grammar (perhaps because it is being machine-generated from the grammar).

A simple recursive descent parser might look something like this (in a recent Python version, with the so-called walrus operator `:=`). I use the convention that a parse function for a grammar symbol (terminal or non-terminal) either returns `False` without consuming input, or returns the semantic value associated with the symbol, which must not be `False`.

```py
   def parse_program():
       defs = []
       if not typ := parse_type():
           return False
       if not id := parse_IDENTIFIER():
           return parse_main(defs, typ)
       while True:
           if parse_EQUAL():
                if not value := parse_expression():
                    # Signal error
                if not parse_SEMI():
                    # Signal error
                defs.append(make_var(id, typ, value))
           elif parse_SEMI():
                defs.append(make_var(id, typ, UNINITIALISED))
           else:
                break
           if not typ := parse_type():
               # signal error
           if not id := parse_IDENTIFIER():
               return parse_main(defs, typ)
       # Now expecting only function definitions
       while parse_OPEN_PAREN():
           params = parse_identifier_list()
           if not params:
               params = []
           if not parse_CLOSE_PAREN():
               # signal error
           if not body := parse_body():
               # signal error
           defs.append(make_function(id, typ, params, body))
           if not typ := parse_type():
               # signal error
           if not id := parse_IDENTIFIER():
               return parse_main(defs, typ)
        # If we get here, main wasn't detected
        # Signal error
    
    def parse_main(defs, typ):
        if not parse_MAIN():
            return False
        if not parse_OPEN():
            # Signal error
        if not parse_CLOSE():
            # Signal error
        if not body := parse_body():
            # Signal error
        if typ != TYPE_INT:
            # Signal error
        defs.append(make_main_function(body))
        return defs
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to eliminate backtracking-leading common prefix "int" of program's all tree parts?

Only way would be to hoist the common prefix into a shared production. Incidentally, I don't think you would have the parser distinguish between `main` and any other function declaration - that can be done in the semantic analysis phase, so taking that out you could do something like:

```
program = {declaration}, function_definition, {function_definition};
decl_or_funcdef_prefix = "int", identifier;
declaration =  decl_or_funcdef_prefix, ["=", init_value], ";";
function_definition = decl_or_funcdef_prefix, "(", [formal_params], ")", block;
```

Of course this could get messy really quickly for a realistic grammar - `c`-family grammars are notoriously hard to parse top-down.

Comment: How should the parser determine whether to go with `declaration` or `function_definition` when parsing `program` and encountered `"int"`?

Comment: Based on the next token after the (common) `decl_or_funcdef_prefix` production - `function_definition` starts with a `(`, `declaration` does not.

Comment: But when the parser meets the next token - `=`, `;`, or `(`, it has already entered the procedure of parsing `declaration` or `function_definition`, so it possibly needs to backtrack, or it needs to determine which procedure is "right" at the first place. Is my understand correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right - I guess my thinking has been polluted by having used only back-tracking language parsers for decades :) - To be used in LL(1), your grammar will have to be massaged further to not branch into specific productions until after the common prefix has been parsed, but the principle still holds.

Comment: I would like to express my thankfulness but don't know if comment is the right place for it. But, thank you very much for your patient answer!

Comment: Normally you would up-vote the answer, but it's up to you :)